# Why does `ps | grep -o RandomString` always print `RandomString`?

Tags: string, bash, grep, ps

```
$echo "one two three four five" | grep -o six # No output

$whoami | grep -o 'ChuckNorris' # No output

$whoami | grep -o 'remi'
remi

$ps | grep -o RandomString
RandomString
```

Why does `ps | grep -o RandomString` outputs 'RandomString' even though the term 'RandomString' does not appear in the output of `ps`?

When using a pattern that matches once, the term is printed several times. For example

```
$ps | grep -o 25541
25541
25541
```

---

If needed, I am on Mac OSX 10.11.3

Comment: `RandomString` *does* appear in the output of `ps` when you run that pipeline, because it's in the arguments to `grep`.

Comment: Drop the `-o` and you'll see why. (`grep -o` just prints the part of the line that matches the pattern. Dropping the `-o` will show the entire line.)

Comment: ...this is part of the point of using `pgrep` -- which leaves both itself and its ancestors out of the result list.